# Generating a graph with greek or arabic symbols

Tags: python, graphviz

I am using a combination of networkx, pygraphviz and graphviz to create and visualise graphs in python,
However I keep encountering utf-8 encoding errors when writing my dot file from my networkx graph that has greek letters as nodes.
I would like to be able to create dot graphs with nodes such as these: Κύριος, Θεός, Πᾶσα, Μέγας, Νέμεσις but am unable to do so.

Are there any encoding tricks I need to know about?

Comment: Could you add some of the code that you have written so far?

Comment: Here this following example doesnt work due to an encoding error:
The dot file doestn seem to be able to be written due to encoding issues.

import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
import graphviz as grv

n = "Νέμεσις"

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_node(n)

write_dot(G, 'test.dot')
grv.render('neato', 'svg', 'graphe.dot')

Comment: Which python version are you using? Could you also post your traceback?

Comment: Python version 3.9.8
graphviz==0.20
networkx==2.8
pydot==1.4.2

[link](https://pastebin.com/0zrUQ8zc) and here is the traceback

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted works fine for me (using ipython with python 3.7) when using the correct dot file path.

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
import graphviz as grv

n = "Νέμεσις"
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(n)
write_dot(G, 'test.dot')
grv.render('neato', 'svg', 'test.dot')
```

Comment: have you tried using a windows machine? My entire project is built around a user interface to customize graphs using streamlit, and there seems to be some differences between the windows and linux versions of the packages, I built it using windows (where I found the issues) and now i am noticing differences when making the code run on linux